# ID based custom taxonomy term url wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

In wordpress the default url structure for custom taxonomy term is something like this http://example.com/%taxonomy-slug%/%term-slug%/. How can I make the url structure of custom taxonomy term like this http://example.com/%taxonomy-slug%/%term-id%/. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have tried going to permalink settings?

Comment: Yes but I did not find anything related to custom taxonomy term permalink....

Comment: I found similar post for you. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/108642/permalinks-custom-post-type-custom-taxonomy-post

Comment: Thats not what I was looking forward... BTW Thanks for your feedback...